# usage of "\" in C?

Tags: c, backslash

I was looking over this code, but i was unable to figure out why the usage of "\" after the && operator?

```
if ((*(u32*)(kaddr + 0x64) == *(u32*)(kaddr + 0x78)) && \
    (*(u32*)(kaddr + 0x68) == *(u32*)(kaddr + 0x88)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` right before the end of the line glues the following line to the current. Since C normally ignores whitespace, this is mostly useful when declaring macros.

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is not needed, unless this is part of a `#define`.

From the C specification §5.1.1.2

> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a
>   new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form
>   logical source lines.

But it's not needed since the C language doesn't require that an `if` statement be placed on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Among its uses are Macro definitions, basically it tells the compiler not to stop at the end of the line but rater to continue. example:

```
#define ASSERT_NULL(value)      \
    do {                        \
        if((value) == NULL) {   \
            return true;        \
        }                       \
    } while(NULL)
```

Now, if you won't put `\`, you  won't get the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: To "assert" means to passively require something to be true. If `value` satisfies the requirement that it must be `NULL`, this macro causes the function to return. That's a bit bizarre.